# how get the day name from a date with a variable

Tags: php, html, function, mysqli

i want to use the funtion DAYNAME, but will get this date from a form, and depends of the day of the week, the person who create the form will win more points

i think something like this

```
if ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Monday") {
$suma1=1;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Tuesday"){
    $suma1=1;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Wednesday"){
    $suma1=1;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Thursday"){
    $suma1=1;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Friday"){
    $suma1=1;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Saturday"){
    $suma1=2;
} elseif ($row['DAYNAME($Data)'] == "Sunday"){
    $suma1=2;
}
```

the problem is here

i have this...

```
 <?php
$db = "sp28";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT DAYNAME("2017-04-06")') as $row) {  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['DAYNAME("2017-04-06")'] . "</td>";   
echo "</tr>";
```

but i want have like this, the variable in DAYNAME,but it doesnt work

```
<?php
$Data="2017-04-06";
$db = "sp28";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT DAYNAME("$Data")') as $row) {  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['DAYNAME("$Data")'] . "</td>";   
echo "</tr>";  

}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - what you want to have and what you have right now? Also I see no function here. Also what you quote `$Date` for? And finally do not post your passwords....

Comment: Also do use some kind of array or just test the Saturday and Sunday

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_day_name_column = DAYNAME('$Data')"`

Comment: But you should be using a prepared parameterized query as the date is coming from a user input

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for answer and how i do for use a prepared parameterized query, sorry but i am newbie on this kind of php

Comment: Start here [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski do you undestand now?